# Android обработчик касаний

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

Пишу приложение, где надо перетаскивать картинки. Использую `onClickListener`. Когда отпускаю картинку, она не останавливается, а срабатывает `ACTION_MOVE`. Чтобы картинка не переместилась, надо очень аккуратно отпускать. 
Как решить эту проблему? Читала про какой то таймер, но не поняла

Comment: Причем тут `OnClickListener`? Когда нужно юзать `OnDragListener`.

Comment: click - это нажать и тут же отпустить. Не очень подходит для обработки перетаскиваний.

Comment: [OnTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener).
[Ссылка на урок](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/167-urok-102-touch-obrabotka-kasanija.html).